# DatePicker control Silverlight 3 Behaviour

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have datepicker control in my form, when user enter some invalid text, or some other character using keyboard, then the text property doesn't show the user entered text which is invalid, But the arguments in the DateValidationError function does containt the invalid user input in the e.Text property, how do I get that invalid user input from the datepicker control text property ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you mean "the DateValidationError function doesn't contain the invalid user input in the e.Text property" ?

Comment: Can you provide a few more details, in my simple testing e.Text contains the text that failed

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that e.Text does containt the invalid user input but the datapicker text property does not contact the invalid user input.